# How to increase POST timeout to api-server when init kubernet cluster witth kubeadm

Tags: kubernetes

When I provision a Kubernetes cluster, I always see that all the POST request sent to API is 10s. How can I increase this value because sometimes 10s are not enough and get a timeout error?

Below are some examples, I see when init.

POST https://192.168.1.88:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps?timeout=10s 201 Created in 552 milliseconds

POST https://192.168.1.88:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/serviceaccounts?timeout=10s 201 Created in 302 milliseconds

POST https://192.168.1.88:6443/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/kube-system/rolebindings?timeout=10s 201 Created in 1186 milliseconds
POST https://192.168.1.88:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps?timeout=10s 201 Created in 552 milliseconds